# Kinesis stream exactly deliver once to one among multiple consumer

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I am setting up kinesis stream with 2 shards. One publisher pumps a packet into each shard at a time. Making sure that no duplication on publisher side. I have setup 2 consumer subscribing to both shards.
I want each packet to be delivered exactly once to one of the consumer.
But kinesis dispatches packets to both consumer, which is causing duplicate data processing.

Is there a way to make kinesis deliver packet exactly once to only one of the consumer?

I tried setting same consumer name to share kinesis checkpointing, but at some point name clashes and one consumer fails. Setting different consumer name results in same packet delivered to both consumers.